# How to create Win 11 Pro Desktop Shortcut for FFMPEG

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, cmd.exe

I have FFMpeg in the (x86) folder and I've permanently appended the fully qualified path to the environmental variables.  Installing FFMPeg does not create an entry in Windows 11 Apps.

I can run FFMPeg by first opening a command prompt window and then typing FFMpeg.  If I attempt to create a desktop shortcut, I see the command window flash open and then close; or I see the command window open but FFMpeg does not start.

I've tried variations like `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` with the `/k` switch only to get the same result.

How can I create a Windows desktop shortcut that will open a command window and run FFMpeg?

Comment: " FFMPEG is a ***command-line*** tool used for processing video and audio files. " https://www.vdocipher.com/blog/how-to-use-ffmpeg

Comment: You'll need to create a script that does what you want, and then create a shortcut to the script.

Answer (score -1):

I successfully created a shortcut with the following options:

```
Target:    C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K ffmpeg
Start in:  <left blank>
```

I also achieved the same by creating a macro that executes:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> **>** <kbd>R</kbd>  **>** `cmd /K ffmpeg` **>** <kbd>Enter</kbd>